# Add Join to this LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using the following query and am having trouble figuring out how to add a join into it:

```
var chi = Lnq.attlnks.Where(a => a.ownerid == emSysid)
                     .Select(c => new { sysid });
```

How can I join this to the "attach" table `(ON attlnks.sysid = attach.sysid)` and select "name" where sysid is the row id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For joins in Linq the query expression form is typically more readable than lambda syntax - I believe this is what you are asking for:

```
var chi = from t in Lnq.attach
          join a in Lnq.attlnks
          on t.sysid equals a.sysid
          where a.ownerid == emSysid
          select t.name;
```

If there is only a single entry that should match at most, you can chain a `FirstOrDefault()` in this case (or other alternatives like SingleOrDefault, Single, First etc.):

```
var chi = (from t in Lnq.attach
          join a in Lnq.attlnks
          on t.sysid equals a.sysid
          where a.ownerid == emSysid
          select t.name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am familiar with the method syntax, so doing it in Lambda is a mess then ?  I kind of got that impression from looking at the examples I found, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, this should work fine:

```
var query = from a in attlinks
     join aa in attach on a.sysid equals aa.sysid into a2
     where a2.sysid == a2.ownerid 
     select a2.Name;
```